# How to remove background color after setting autocomplete="on"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please consider me as a beginner of web developing. The problem is, when I turn autocomplete on in a `<form></form>` environment, the color of search box becomes white from black (perhaps it's set by flex I guess?). I am wondering is there any way to keep color unchanged.

```html
<form autocomplete="on">
    <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
        <label id="email" for="email" style="padding-right:5px">email:</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" style="flex:1" placeholder="e.g. aaa@bbb.com" />
        <button id="ack" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

*search box initial color: black (by flex?)*: 
[image]
*color after autocompletion*: 
[image]

Comment: Autocomplete highlighting may be done by the Browser, without you being able to do anything about it.

Comment: If you right click the element giving you trouble and select "Inspect", it will show you the exact styles being applied. My first guess would be that it's related to your browser.

Comment: Do you reset default styles?

Comment: Maybe `autofill` browser default CSS.

Comment: @StackSlave There are workarounds, so I'm not sure I'd go as far as saying "You can't do anything about it". `background` in particular is a nasty one but you can employ some JavaScript (albeit ugly, admittedly) to circumvent it.

Comment: You guys are right, if I use IE browser, it doesn't  change background color. Just to make it clear, there is no (simple) way to set this style in html / javascript code, is it correct?

Comment: @EI. I am not sure what function flex has. I do not reset other styles except for flex.

Comment: I found this selector using the dev tools in chrome: `input:-internal-autofill-selected` but I was unable to override it even with `background-color: white !important;`. It showed that the chrome specific styling was overridden but did not change the background colour to white. Try some of these perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56837713/8620333